# Как вывести значения переменной через запятую в WP get_terms?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть код:

```
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'label',
    'parent'   => 146,
]);

if (!empty($terms)) {
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        echo $term->name;
    
        $posts = get_posts([
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                   'taxonomy' => 'label',
                   'field'    => 'id',
                   'terms'    => [$term->term_id]
                ]
            ],
           'post_type' => 'post', // Или другой пост тайп
           'posts_per_page' => -1
        ]);

        foreach($posts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post); ?>
        
        <?php   
            $title = $post->post_title; 
            echo $title;
        ?>

        <?php endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Нужно переменную **$title** вывести через запятую, но ничего не получается. Пробовала **preg_replace**, **explode**, **implode**, **регулярки** и везде результат отрицательный. Если смотреть вывод в html, то **echo $title;** выводит вот так:

```
        Заголовок 1         
     
        Заголовок 2         

        Заголовок 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) :
            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

            <?php
            $title = $post->post_title;
            echo $title;
            ?>

        <?php endforeach;
```

вставьте

```
        $titles = [];

        foreach ( $posts as $post ) :
            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

            <?php
            $titles[] = $post->post_title;
            ?>

        <?php endforeach;

        echo implode( ', ', $titles );
```

Этот кусок кода собирает все ваши заголовки в массив, а потом их выводит строкой через запятую.

Comment: В принципе получилось :) но почему то отступы огромные по прежнему.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде вывела то что надо)

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены, что вам нужны эти чудо выводы? Есть простое решение через `CSS`

```css
h2:not(:nth-last-of-type(1))::after {
  content: ",";
}
```

```html
<h2>Text1</h2>
<h2>Text2</h2>
<h2>Text3</h2>
<h2>Text4</h2>
<h2>Text5</h2>
```

Comment: Нет, нужно строго php, это только малая часть вывода.